# cURL works while accessing GitHub /search/users API but using restTemplate.exchange returns zero users

Tags: java, spring, curl, github-api, resttemplate

I have defined a RestTemplate backed HttpClient to call Github API to search users

My method is this

```
public List<User> fetchPublicInformation(String firstName, String lastName, String location) {

    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    if (token != null && token.length() != 0) {
        headers.set("Authorization", "bearer " + token);
    }
    headers.set("'User-Agent'", "request");
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

    synchronized (this) {

        StringBuilder uri = new StringBuilder(GITHUB_SEARCH + "users?q=fullname:");
        if (!firstName.isEmpty()) {
            uri.append(firstName.trim().toLowerCase());
        } else {
            firstName = " ";
        }
        if (!lastName.isEmpty()) {
            uri.append(" " + lastName.trim().toLowerCase());
        } else {
            lastName = " ";
        }
        if (location != null && !location.isEmpty()) {
            uri.append("+location:" + location.trim().toLowerCase());
        }
        System.out.println(uri.toString());
        ResponseEntity<GitHubUsersResponse> response = null;
        response = template.exchange(uri.toString(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, GitHubUsersResponse.class);
        return response.getBody().getItems();
    }
}
```

This method hits the URI

```
https://api.github.com/search/users?q=fullname:shiva tiwari+location:bangalore
```

and return [] as Items(part of response Body)

while if I use the same URI with cURL it gives me four responses.

I am unable to find my fault.

Comment: if I use the uri you posted with `curl` (`curl 'https://api.github.com/search/users?q=fullname:shiva tiwari+location:bangalore'`) I get "400 Bad Request", I belive due to the space character `' '` in "shiva tiwari". if I replace the space with `+` or `%20` I get a json object with an "items" property that contains `[]` (empty array). same result if I use a browser.

Comment: If I execute "curl https://api.github.com/search/users?q=fullname:shiva tiwari+location:bangalore" in macOS terminal , I get valid result

Comment: @MarcoLucidi I don't think we need curl 2 times

Comment: you don't need "`curl` 2 times", I put the command I run inside round brackets (). try running this command: `curl 'https://api.github.com/search/users?q=fullname:shiva tiwari+location:bangalore'`. what do you get? now try this: `curl 'https://api.github.com/search/users?q=fullname:shiva+tiwari+location:bangalore'`. what do you get?

Comment: cURL runs fine, its the Java which is giving blank result.

Comment: please define what you mean with "runs fine", since with `curl` I get same result as java (empty items list). can you post your curl output? mine is `{
  "total_count": 0,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [

  ]
}`.

Comment: Rishis-MacBook-Pro:~ rishiprakash$ curl https://api.github.com/search/users?q=fullname:shiva tiwari+location:bangalore
{
  "total_count": 1230,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [
    {
      "login": "Shiva108",
      "id": 13223532,
I get multiple results.

Comment: you get this result because of the space in the url I mentioned in my first comment! curl is not using the full url, but just `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=fullname:shiva` and is not the same url java is using. try the two commands I told you before: the first will fail (I get 400 bad request), the second will report the same result as java (items: []). spaces are used to separate arguments in the shell and needs to be properly escaped.

Comment: @MarcoLucidi wow..got your point. Many many thanks :) Probably you can write an answer for this and I can accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

investigating with OP in the comments, we found out that he was not using the same url of java with `curl`, so he was getting different results.

he was running this command:

```
$ curl https://api.github.com/search/users?q=fullname:shiva tiwari+location:bangalore
{
  "total_count": 1230,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [
    {
      "login": "Shiva108",
      "id": 13223532,
...
```

which produces an output that contains several objects inside the "items" array while with java code he was getting an empty "items" array.

the space character `' '` in the url is crucial! the shell uses spaces to separate arguments of commands and they need to be properly escaped when they are inside arguments.

the url OP was using with `curl` was in fact just `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=fullname:shiva`, the last part was being interpreted as another argument to `curl` (and produced also an error `curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`) while java was using the full url including the surname and location filter.

a literal space `' '` inside an url is also an illegal character and needs to be encoded using `+` or `%20` (see [Percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)), in fact, if we use quotes `'` to escape the space in the shell, we get "400 Bad Request":

```
$ curl -v 'https://api.github.com/search/users?q=fullname:shiva tiwari+location:bangalore'
...
< HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
...
```

but with proper space encoding we get the same result as java (empty "items" array):

```
$ curl 'https://api.github.com/search/users?q=fullname:shiva+tiwari+location:bangalore'
{
  "total_count": 0,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [

  ]
}
$
```

(I'm pretty sure java code handles space encoding automatically)